# Drop down Quake-style terminal for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line

I am looking for a gratis Windows command prompt program, which will drop down and slide back out of the way on a hotkey.

Nice to have features are command history search and tabbed, multiple consoles.

Does anyone have experience of a few, rather than just Googling? Is there anything with even more features that the few which I have asked for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better than Qonsole, there is the wonderful Windows terminal emulator [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) (instead of cmd, console2 etc.) which has native support for Quake-style dropdown terminal. I am using it as we speak.

See here for a nice Windows terminal emulator shootout:

https://aarontgrogg.com/blog/2015/07/31/a-better-windows-command-line-experience-comparing-powercmd-vs-console2-vs-consolez-vs-conemu-vs-cmder/

Comment: I hav ejust started using ConEmu, which I remember having used and liked, but lost track of after a reinstall, several years ago.  Subjecttively, it seems slow, but maybe I have not yet configured it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard about Qonsole and it may be exactly what you're looking for. It's a Quake-like Console Emulator written in AutoHotkey.

## [Qonsole (open source)](https://github.com/joedf/Qonsole)

> #### Features
>
> - Custom hotkey
> - Slide up & down animation
> - Enable Ctrl+v Console pasting
> - Transparency options
> - Configurable with cmd & console2
> - Background screen dimmer
> - Internal Update check, (automatic, 5 min after start up)
> - Optionally Run Qonsole when Windows Starts
> - More...
>
> [image: Qonsole screenshot]

Comment: I Googled & found a bunch, some of which have command history search and tabbed, multiple consoles, unlike this one, apparently. I had really hoped that someone would have experience of one/some, to sae me from having to download, install & try them all out.